# converting file with unspecified number of lines, by using regex, visual c#

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2015

I have an app which converts a file,by reading all lines from source text file and printing only lines which contain word:'student'.Also removes some characters and splits the printed line into 5 fields as shown below:

input text file

```
Form|01; 23_anna- Member 12569 is student - 12*01*2006
Form|02; 17_smith_ Member 12570 is teacher - 13*01*2007
Form|03; 12_ben_ Member 12571 is student - 14*01*2007
```

The output file:

```
Form01 anna 12569 student 12 01 2006
Form03 ben 12571 student 14 01 2007
```

The code i have tried:

```
 private Regex find = new Regex(@"^(.+?)(?:\|)(\d+)(?:.+?_)(.+?)(?:[_-] Member ?)(\d+)(?:.+?)(student)(?:.+?)(\d\d).(\d\d).(\d\d\d\d)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sample = "Form|01; 23_anna- Member 12569 is student - 12*01*2006\nForm|02; 17_smith_ Member 12570 is teacher - 13*01*2007\nForm|03; 12_ben_ Member 12571 is student - 14*01*2007";
    MatchCollection matches = find.Matches(sample);
    foreach (Match m in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} {2} {3} is {4} {5} {6} {7}", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3], m.Groups[4], m.Groups[5], m.Groups[6], m.Groups[7], m.Groups[8]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```

But how can I change the code if I want to convert a file with more lines( ~ 500 lines)

Comment: What is the exact problem? Performance? 500 lines should not be a problem.

Comment: Just read your file line by line and apply your code to each line

Comment: my code runs only for the sample of 3 lines, but I dont wan't to be specified, I want to read a file from a path, after reading all lines one by one and to print with specified conditions.How can I change ?

Comment: `foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filename)) …` ?

Comment: thnx, should I change the regex and the string sample part? or only the condition foreach?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this in my opinion is to use `File.ReadAllLines()` then in a foreach loop do your regex. I also think that you are overcomplicating your regex so I have made a few changes where I think it can be simplified.

Working under the assumption that the format of the string you are looking for will always be the same. Since form and student are in all of these lines then I see little reason to capture it. In reality there are 6 key pieces of information to capture.

1 – the numbers after form
2 – the name
3 – the 5-digit member number
4,5,6 – the three sections of the date

Everything else is either constant or not used in the output string. So when we come to rewrite the search and replace we get something like:

`/^\w+\|([^;]+).+?([a-z]+)[^\d]+(\d{5})[^\d]+(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})/m`

`Console.WriteLine("Form{0} {1} {2} student {3} {4} {5}", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3], m.Groups[4], m.Groups[5], m.Groups[6])`

Note that there are assumptions in the regex such as the name is always in lower case and the member number is always 5 digits and some other stuff like there can't be numbers in the names etc. It isn't optimal but I think it is tidier than yours, but this is personal preference I guess.

To get the lines with student use `string.Contains("student")` or if you really want to include it in your regex I would recommend using a positive lookahead for student `(?=.*student)`

Here is a bit of example code I wrote for one way that I would do it:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\w+\|([^;]+).+?([a-z]+)[^\d]+(\d{5})[^\d]+(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})$",RegexOptions.Multiline);
var file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:temp\test.txt");

            foreach(var line in file)
            {
                if (line.Contains("student"))
                {
                    var m = regex.Match(line);
                    Console.WriteLine("Form{0} {1} {2} student {3} {4} {5}", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3], m.Groups[4], m.Groups[5], m.Groups[6]);
                }
            }
```